# Why is UIImage nil if i have the Data

Tags: swift, image, sqlite

I am able to confirm that the data exists however when I try to convert this to `UIImage` it is `nil`. Why would this not convert to an image if the data is there?

```
let data = Data(bytes: dataBlob, count: Int(dataBlobLength)) // this is a Data
let image = UIImage(data: data) // this is nil
```

I'm getting the data from SQLite by way of from `.mbtiles` which I downloaded from openmaptiles. I'm fairly certain that the data is from jpeg and png images.

```
guard let dataBlob = sqlite3_column_blob(queryStatement, 0) else { return nil }   
let dataBlobLength = sqlite3_column_bytes(queryStatement, 0)
```

Any ideas for debugging or why this might happen?

Comment: You are making a mistake at the very last line.

Comment: @ElTomato the `dataBlobLength` line?

Comment: Yes.  But who knows!?  You don't show us how to insert your blob data into a database.

Comment: I didn't insert it. I'm just querying it. I got the data from openmaptiles. When I log `po dataBlob` and `po dataBlobLength` I see that they exist.

Comment: Find out the data type for the column with which you are trying to return data.

Comment: "MBTiles supports PNG, PNG8, and JPEG data stored as binary blobs"

Comment: I suggest you read all topics regarding SQLite and blob so that you will find out why you need data from two fields to make an image.

Comment: @LeoDabus the `dataBlob` is a `UnsafeRawPointer` so I think the only init for Data is `.init(bytes: count:)`?

Comment: The initializer it is correct. Do you know what type of image you are downloading?

Comment: Try writing your data to disk (PNG, JPEG or whatever). I guess it is a jpeg image. And try to open it

Comment: I used `data.write(to: options:)` where data is `Data(bytes: dataBlob, count: Int(dataBlobLength))` and when I opened the jpeg file it says `It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.` I know its not damaged though because I was able to render the same images inside this exact .mbtiles SQLite DB on the web. I guess this proves the way I'm creating the data is incorrect. Though I'm not sure how else to if I'm given an `UnsafeRawPointer`.

Comment: So I guess your data might be base64EncodedData. Try decoding it `UIImage(data: Data(base64Encoded: data))`

Comment: So it looks like the blob is a PBF file and not jpg or png